# Parallel processing of files inside a ZipInputStream

Tags: java, algorithm, parallel-processing

Here is my code:

```
ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ZipEntry ze;
while ((ze = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    String filePath = ze.getName();
    ByteArrayOutputStream streamBuilder = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[8192*2];
    while ( (bytesRead = zipStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1 ){
    streamBuilder.write(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] byteArray = streamBuilder.toByteArray();
    writeFile(filePath, byteArray); // need to call this in parallel
}
```

The problems:

- The writeFile function is called in serial manner causing the overall time to `writeFile`s a bit long (in our case 5 mins by average)
- What kind of parallelism or parallel execution pattern can be applied here to be able to call the writeFile function simultaneously, example 8 `writeFile` per loop?

Comment: Assuming writeFile indeed writes a file, writing in parallel to the same disk will make things even slower. Parallelization is not the answer here.

Comment: If that takes 5 minutes to execute, if must be a huge file, and is very likely I/O bound, not CPU bound, so making it multi-threaded will do nothing, except unnecessarily complicating the code. As JB just said, it might actually slow it down. Only way to improve speed, is to replace harddrives with faster ones, e.g. SSD, But, before doing anything, look at the program run, and see if it is CPU or I/O that's causing the problem. Don't guess. Measure.

Comment: @JBNizet writeFile actually writes to MongoDB GridFS so it is fast

Comment: @Andreas the problem I see is the the writeFile calls for REST API connecting to GridFS

Comment: Then create an ExecutorService, and submit a task to this executor service for each filepath/byte array pair. Adjust the number of threads in the pool based on your measurements to obtain the best throughput. I don't know anything about GridFS, but if it consists on several distributed nodes each writing on their own disk, the best number of threads is probably the number of nodes.

Comment: @xybrek Don't you think the fact that `writeFile()` doesn't actually write a file to the file system, but instead is a REST call, would be relevant to the question? Edit the question and clarify it.